# vba insert array formula using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to insert an array formula into a cell in excel, however I get an error, "unable to set the formula array for the range class"

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
intRow4 As Integer, _

intRow4 = excWks4.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

lastcell = excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 4).Address

theform = "=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$A$1:$G$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT(" & lastcell & ",5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),6)),"""",INDEX('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$A$1:$G$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT(" & lastcell & ",5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),6))"

excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 5).FormulaArray = theform
```

Comment: Where is `lastcell` defined?

Comment: at the top of my code, have edited my code to reflect this

Comment: If I manually enter your formula in a cell I get a circular reference error.  Are you sure your references are correct?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104(v=office.15).aspx) -

> If you use this property to enter an array formula, the formula must
>   use the R1C1 reference style, not the A1 reference style

So you need to replace `$A$1` with `$R1$C1` etc.

Comment: thanks I tried this but I get a object doesn't support this property or method error

Answer (score 0):

**FormulaArray** has a [255 character limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104(v=office.15).aspx).  Yours is at least 309 characters, depending on the length of `lastcell`.

You could get under 256 characters by shortening your worksheet name.